# Can you edit Node type in the keymap?

Tags: node-editor, shortcut

[image]

When I'm editing my keymap, I'm able to create custom Node creation shortcuts, however, for nodes that have multiple options (eg Math node can be Add, Subtract, Multiply etc) I can't seem to specify any parameters without breaking the shortcut.

When I type in node.add_node, I'm given the Node Type, Use Transform, and "0 items" options. Is it possible to pass in this variable using these "items", and, if so, what is the proper syntax? 
Whenever I type anything else in either the node.add_node, or ShaderNodeMath boxes the shortcut stops working.

I have checked the docs and can't find any references to what the "items" can be, or how to activate them. I know there are add-ons that do this, but I'm wondering if it's possible just in the keymap?

Comment: To be clear, what I'm trying to achieve it this:  


`node.add_node(type="ShaderNodeMath", use_transform=True, settings=[{"name":"operation", "value":"'MULTIPLY'"}])`  

But adding anything, even just empty brackets, causes the shortcut to stop working.  

Is it possible to add the "settings=" variables in the "0 items" area? And what do I need to do to enable it?